# How to change the color of a word in a line of text with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on an assignment to create a form with HTML and JS that accepts a username, email, phone number, etc. and then validates that data. If the field is empty a message should print saying "Please enter " followed by whatever is missing in red text. The same with if the data is incorrect except the text should be orange.

I have gotten all the validation done and the messages print to the screen when appropriate, but I can't figure out how to change the last word's color.

This is a portion of the code just for the username validation:

```
let username = "username";

if (user == "") {
    out.innerText = "Please enter " + username + "\n";
   // out.innerText += <span class="empty">${username}</span> + "\n";
   // out.innerText += username.style.color="red" + "\n"
  } else if(user.length < 4 || user.length > 12) {
    out.innerText = "Please enter a valid username\n";
  } else {
    count++;
  }
```

The CSS for the class "empty":

```
.empty {
    color: red;
}
```

I left in what I've tried so far. Everything I've tried either stops the messages from printing to the screen altogether or it prints it all out and ignores the span tags.

Comment: You have to use innerHTML if you are adding html tags.

Comment: If you can skip the color change requirement, HTML 5 browser input validation attributes are state of the art. Check out `INPUT` attributes `required`, `minLength`, and `maxLength`. Put those in, and when you try to submit the FORM, it will automatically tell the user where their problem is

Comment: @ControlAltDel The assignment actually is for us to manually validate all the fields with JavaScript only lol

Answer (score 0):

Based of on your specific code, you should use `Element.innerHTML` and preferably String Literals, also `username` is not equal to `user`.

```js
const out = document.querySelector("#out");

const username = "";
let count = 0;

if (username === "") {
  out.innerHTML = `<span class="err">Username is empty</span>`;
} else if (username.length < 4 || username.length > 12) {
  out.innerHTML = `<span class="warn">${username} is not valid</span>`;
} else {
  count++;
}
```

```css
.err { color: red; }
.warn { color: orange; }
```

```html
<div id="out"></div>
```

Comment: So when I use this in my program the first outcome will print, but not with the color and the second one doesn't print at all. Also, the user that I have in the original code refers to `user = document.infoForm.name.value;` I only created username so that I could change the color since <span> wasn't working for me.

Comment: @MaliaCherry works: https://jsfiddle.net/do9qapyb/